# How to delete every 2nd character in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

How to delete every 2nd character in a string?

For example:

```
3030313535333635  -> 00155365
3030303336313435  -> 00036145
3032323437353530  -> 02247550
```

The strings are always 16-characters long and the result is always 8 characters long - and the character that is being removed is always a '3' - Don't ask why however - I did not dream up this crazy source data.

Comment: iterate the string and take the every alternate character and construct a string And discard the rest.

Comment: I know why: the left hand strings are paired hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII codes of the characters on the right.  What you should do is take pairs of characters, parse them as hexadecimal, and build a string out of the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String input = "3030313535333635";
String result = "";
for(int i = 1; i < 16; i +=2 )
{
    result += input[i];
}
```

Comment: You're making `StringBuilder` sad :(

Comment: I thought about it, but then I thought "*Hey, it's only 8 characters*" ;)

Comment: That's OK, it's just nice to see a good old fashioned loop win over Linq for a change :)

Answer (score 12):

Try this to get the every other character from the string:-

```
 var s = string.Join<char>("", str.Where((ch, index) => (index % 2) != 0));
```

Comment: Nice but (index % 2) == 0 should be (index % 2) != 0

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Why `string.Join("", seq)` when you could `string.Concat(seq)`?

Comment: I think both can perform the task but I prefered string.Join. Plz correct me if there is anything wrong in using it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this well-known class [`System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx) :)

```
string str = "3030313535333635";
var hex = System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary.Parse(str);
var newstr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hex.Value);
```

Comment: @pst See the BenVoigt's comment

Answer (score 3):

Using a `StringBuilder` to create a string will save resources

```
string input = "3030313535333635";
var sb = new StringBuilder(8); // Specify capacity = 8
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i += 2) {
    sb.Append(input[i]);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in Java Language

```
String input= "3030313535333635"
String output="";

for(int i=1;i<input.length();i=i+2)
{
    output+=input.charAt(i).toString();
}
System.out.println(output);
```